# Cannot Save to CSV from Groupby

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Iam newbie in python. I have huge a `dataframe` with millions of rows and id. my data looks like this:

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
9:00    B   24  110
10:00   B   25  120
11:00   C   26  130
12:00   C   27  140
13:00   A   28  150
14:00   A   29  160
15:00   D   30  170
16:00   C   31  180
17:00   B   32  190
18:00   A   33  200
19:00   C   34  210
20:00   A   35  220
21:00   B   36  230
22:00   C   37  240
23:00   B   38  250
```

I sorted the data on id and time.

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
13:00   A   28  150
14:00   A   29  160
18:00   A   33  200
20:00   A   35  220
9:00    B   24  110
10:00   B   25  120
17:00   B   32  190
21:00   B   36  230
23:00   B   38  250
11:00   C   26  130
12:00   C   27  140
16:00   C   31  180
19:00   C   34  210
22:00   C   37  240
15:00   D   30  170
```

and I want to pick only "The first and the last" of the id and eliminate the rest. The result looked like this:

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
20:00   A   35  220
9:00    B   24  110
23:00   B   38  250
11:00   C   26  130
22:00   C   37  240
15:00   D   30  170
```

I used this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("contoh.csv")
g = df.groupby('ID')
(pd.concat([g.head(1), g.tail(1)])
   .drop_duplicates()
   .sort_values('ID')
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

It works but I cannot save to csv

```
g.to_csv('result.csv')
```

I got an error message: `Cannot access callable attribute 'to_csv' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

any advice to me? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the concat function, you are not applying it on the groupby object g. You need to reassign the concat function's output to another object.

```
df = pd.read_csv("contoh.csv")
g = df.groupby('ID')
g_1 = pd.concat([g.head(1),g.tail(1)]).drop_duplicates().sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
g_1.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: great way. thank you so much. would you mind to give advance way to add another  "annotation" column include head and tail to assign every result row? @Ernest

Comment: @Arief I don't understand your question fully? can you give an example?